# How to correctly find, monitor and handle deprecated method calls in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, deprecation-warning

I have just updated a Symfony 2.7 project to 2.8. Now I am preparing to update the project to Symfony 3. The Profile shows, that a great number (over 1500) of deprecated methods/classes are used on each request.

Of course I would like to solve these issues. However as far as I can tell, the deprecated code is uses by Symfony itself and not by my own code.

Here is an example:

```
ConfigCache::__toString() is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the getPath() method instead. (4 times)

    ConfigCache::__toString() (called from AllowedMethodsRouterLoader.php at line 51)
    AllowedMethodsRouterLoader::getAllowedMethods() (called from AllowedMethodsRouterLoader.php at line 51)
    AllowedMethodsRouterLoader::getAllowedMethods() (called from AllowedMethodsListener.php at line 41)
    AllowedMethodsListener::onKernelResponse()
    call_user_func() (called from WrappedListener.php at line 61)
    WrappedListener::__invoke()
    call_user_func() (called from EventDispatcher.php at line 184)

    ...a lot more Twig calls...

    Twig_Template::displayWithErrorHandling() (called from Template.php at line 347)
    Twig_Template::display() (called from Template.php at line 358)
    Twig_Template::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 50)
    TwigEngine::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 72)
    TwigEngine::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 97)
    TwigEngine::renderResponse() (called from Controller.php at line 185)
    Controller::render() (called from RegistrationController.php at line 71)

    RegistrationController::registerAction()

    call_user_func_array() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 144)
    HttpKernel::handleRaw() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 64)
    HttpKernel::handle() (called from ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69)
    ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() (called from Kernel.php at line 185)
    Kernel::handle() (called from app_dev.php at line 37)
```

Of course my own code also involved in this call stack: The `RegistrationController` handled the request and used a `Twig` template to render the page. However the code that uses the deprecated `ConfigCache::__toString()` method is from within the `AllowedMethodsRouterLoader` class, which is part of Symfony.

**Is there anything my code can do to avoid this deprecated code?**

I am quite surprised, that Symfony code itself uses deprecated code. It there any way to filter out these messages and only get notified about deprecations in my own code?

Comment: This just means that Sensio Labs has marked certain pieces of code as deprecated for version 3 in the 2.8 code.  It's normal to have those notices and actually diligent on their part to mark them.  It lets you know what to expect before you make that 3.x upgrade.  Any code marked as deprecated in symfony core will be updated for version 3, so you don't need to worry about those.

Comment: A `deprecated` notice means, that a certain piece of code *can* still be used but it *shouldn't* be use, because it will be removed in the next release. Using such code *after* the update to version 3 would break the code. Thus one should check ones **own** code and remove the usage of deprecated code. BUT: Its not my code that uses the deprecated parts but the Symfony code itself. Do I have to do anything about this?

Comment: No you don't.  I'm well aware of what deprecation means. But thanks for the explanation.  Basically modify *your* code before you transition to Symfony3.  They will be updating their core.  This is their way of letting you know what's happening.  Think of it this way.... While they are building version 3, they are going in marking any code in 2.8 that changes to 'deprecated', that way when people use 2.8 they get a heads up about what to expect change-wise when they move to 3.  This is totally normal. Don't edit the core code.

Comment: I understand everything you say and agree a 100%. However this is not an answer to my question :) Assume there is some method `SomClass::old()` which is now deprecated. The method `SomeClass::new()` should be used instead. Marking `old()` as `depreacted` is the way the Symfony guys tell me not use this method anymore. Fine, but it does not make any sense that Symfony **itself** still uses this code. This way I get a ton of deprecated message I cannot avoid/influce in any way. Or can I? Of course I will not edit core code, but can I change my own code to avoid this outdated Symfony code?

Comment: Think this way. Way back when Sensio wrote version 2.8 they made the method `SomClass::old()`.  At this time it's not deprecated & people are using it.  Now they are drafting version 3, and in that core they've made an improvement and are using `SomClass:new()`.  *At this moment*, `SomClass::old()` is now *deprecated*... marked for removal in a future version.  You don't go back and update it in 2.8.  You release the modification in 3.  They are not *using* deprecated code, they are improving their code, and some code naturally *becomes* deprecated.  This is the normal life cycle of software.

Comment: At no time did they write a version of symfony using deprecated code.  As versions age and new versions come out, older versions naturally have code that *becomes* deprecated.  2.8 was released in November of 2015.  It's right at about a year old at this point.  Naturally it's going to have some code in it marked as deprecated while they work on future versions.

Comment: OK agreed :) There is still the question, if these messages (caused by Symfonys usage of deprecated message) can be silenced to concentrate on the deprecation messages caused by my own code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124644/discussion-between-robert-wade-and-andrei-herford).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the Deprecation Detector from Sensio Labs ( creator of Symfony ).

[Deprecation Detector on Github](https://github.com/sensiolabs-de/deprecation-detector)

I used it quite a bit removing deprecated classes/methods in 2.8 preparing to move to 3.0. Was a great time saver. Highly recommended.

I'd also recommend [Symfony Upgrade Fixer](https://github.com/umpirsky/Symfony-Upgrade-Fixer) to save even more time especially regarding form classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's running deprecated code - within the Symfony codebase, but it is being called from Twig. Since Twig is a first-class part of Symfony, but not a a formal part of the Symfony project, it has it's own releases. A more up to date version of Twig, as well as other libraries, will have removed the use of deprecated code, or at least done something towards improving the status.

So,  large part of updating a Symfony framework based project, is also updating the rest of the libraries that are also being used. Just updating the `"symfony/symfony"` line in composer.json is not enough.